# How to use another page(not default) to edit user (Devise gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to use another page(not defaule) to edit user (Devise gem) ?

I have this situation: I need some page to add attributes to user, but I want to use edit_user_registration - I want to use another page.

So I need to create another action in registrations controller and add it in routes.rb. Also I created another file in registrations folder, but I have troubles with implementation.

Here is my registrations controller:

```
   def paypal

   end
```

and paypal.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |d| %>
  <%= d.email_field :paypal_email %>
  ...
 <%end%>
```

**Question: what I should write in my routes rb to call paypal action and edit page worked properly?**

```
   devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'} do 
     registrations#paypal//something here instead
   end
```

Comment: Does modifying the default views work? (`rails g devise:views` or so)

Comment: @grilix , I mean - I need ANOTHER PAGE. Edit registration - works, but I need ANTOHER ONE for editing.